# Can i use gsub function to find a pattern and replace it by 2 different patterns?

Tags: r, gsub, character-replacement

I need help with finding a pattern and replacing it by two different ways. For example, the word `"Code/i"` should be replaced with `"Code, Codi"`.

What code should I use in replacement to get two results separated by comma? I am new to R and assuming some metacharacters or regex needs to be used? Also, i need to use base functions and no external packages. Appreciate any feedback and help as im stuck! Thanks

```
a <- c("Code/i", "Karina")

gsub(pattern = "/i", replacement= "", a)
```

Desired outcome:

```
"Code, Codi, Karina"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub` and `paste0` and subset your vector `a` on the relevant values (those that contain the pattern `/`):

Data:

```
a <- c("Code/i", "Karina", "Jimmy", "John Bolton", "Pete/i")
```

Solution:

```
c(paste0(sub("/.*", "", a[grepl("/", a)]), ", ", sub("./", "", a[grepl("/", a)])), a[!grepl("/", a)])
```

Result:

```
[1] "Code, Codi"  "Pete, Peti"  "Karina"      "Jimmy"       "John Bolton"
```

Comment: Have edited the answer a number of times. Now it should be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It definitely works but i am facing yet another issue. If i have other words stored in a like a <- c("Code/i", "Karina"), then the result "Code ,  Codi"       "Karina ,  Karina". What can i do so the code only applies to words that match my criteria?

Comment: Have edited the answer. Please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark if it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you Chris! In the result i need to have all names, including those that were not amended like "Karina". Right now when i apply this code it gives me an error that the length of replacement doesn't match the length of whole data. Any ways to fix it?